# vagrant doesn't see aliases

Tags: apache, vagrant, vagrantfile

I have problem with my vagrant. I have created guest ubuntu 14.04 with the project. Here is my vagrant file

```
# -*- mode: ruby -*-
# vi: set ft=ruby :

Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|
    config.vm.box = "example"

    config.vm.provider :virtualbox do |v|
        v.customize ["modifyvm", :id, "--memory", "4056"]
        v.customize ["modifyvm", :id, "--natdnshostresolver1", "on"]
        v.customize ["modifyvm", :id, "--natdnsproxy1", "on"]
        v.customize ["setextradata", :id, "VBoxInternal2/SharedFoldersEnableSymlinksCreate/home/user/sites/projects-folder", "1"]
        # v.customize ["modifyhd", :id, "--resize", "15360"]
    end

    config.vm.provision :shell, :inline => "sudo apt-get update"

    config.vm.synced_folder "/home/user/sites/projects-folder", "/var/www/projects-folder", create: true, :nfs => true
    config.nfs.map_uid = Process.uid
    config.nfs.map_gid = Process.gid

    config.vm.network :private_network, ip: "33.33.33.11"    
    config.vm.network :forwarded_port, guest: 80, host: 8081

    config.hostsupdater.aliases = ["www.example.local, api.example.local, business.example.local"]

end
```

Here is my config from /etc/apache2/sites-enabled

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin admin@example.com
    ServerName www.example.local
    ServerAlias www.example.local

    DocumentRoot /var/www/projects-folder/www.example/dist

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

when i go to the ip 33.33.33.11 from my host machine I see apache page (so it's works).

But www.example.local - doesn't

Answer (score 0):

Have you installed the hostupdater plugin in vagrant?  You can check your installed plugins by doing,

```
$ vagrant plugin list
```

If hostupdater isn't installed you can install it with,

```
$ vagrant plugin install vagrant-hostsupdater
```